# D3js tooltips for different graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

Assuming I have a dashboard with different graphs shown (for instance: one arc graph, one area graph, a calendar view, etc.). If I hover on one day of that calendar view (ex: 26th of may), I want the other graphs that are in the dashboard at that moment to show the information associated to the day I hovered in the calendar graph(if they do not have information, nothing happens in them). This is applicable to any other graph I choose.

The bottomline here is how do I have this type of dynamic tooltips that know what is happening on the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want are interconnected components that react to one another when an action is performed over one or the other.

What you can do then is the following:

use the

```
.on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseout)
.on("click", clicked)
```

events to trigger any action that you want.

then inside the `click`,`mouseover` or `mouseout` functions that you should define somewhere, you should make changes to the styles/data that impact the other charts (ie, highlighting a specific bar on a barchart, etc)

See the following example which is copy/pasted from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/diethardsteiner/3287802) - I just recreated the code for posterity.

The key here is in the `up` function. That's where you want to update all other tooltips, to reflect the changes. Note that this example changes the entire charts. You can probably adapt that function to update whatever tooltip you are trying to display.

You should adapt it to your own needs, using whatever charts/forms you need.

```js
var  formatAsPercentage = d3.format("%"),
  formatAsPercentage1Dec = d3.format(".1%"),
  formatAsInteger = d3.format(","),
  fsec = d3.time.format("%S s"),
  fmin = d3.time.format("%M m"),
  fhou = d3.time.format("%H h"),
  fwee = d3.time.format("%a"),
  fdat = d3.time.format("%d d"),
  fmon = d3.time.format("%b")
  ;

/*
############# PIE CHART ###################
-------------------------------------------
*/



function dsPieChart(){

 var dataset = [
   {category: "Sam", measure: 0.30},
       {category: "Peter", measure: 0.25},
       {category: "John", measure: 0.15},
       {category: "Rick", measure: 0.05},
       {category: "Lenny", measure: 0.18},
       {category: "Paul", measure:0.04},
       {category: "Steve", measure: 0.03}
       ]
       ;

 var  width = 400,
     height = 400,
     outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
     innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,   
     // for animation
     innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
     innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius* .45,
     color = d3.scale.category20()    //builtin range of colors
     ;
     
 var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
      .append("svg:svg")              //create the SVG element inside the <body>
      .data([dataset])                   //associate our data with the document
          .attr("width", width)           //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
          .attr("height", height)
        .append("svg:g")                //make a group to hold our pie chart
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")    //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius
    ;
    
   var arc = d3.svg.arc()              //this will create <path> elements for us using arc data
         .outerRadius(outerRadius).innerRadius(innerRadius);
   
   // for animation
   var arcFinal = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal).outerRadius(outerRadius);
 var arcFinal3 = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal3).outerRadius(outerRadius);

   var pie = d3.layout.pie()           //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
        .value(function(d) { return d.measure; });    //we must tell it out to access the value of each element in our data array

   var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")     //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
        .data(pie)                          //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties) 
        .enter()                            //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
            .append("svg:g")                //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
               .attr("class", "slice")    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)
               .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout)
        .on("click", up)
        ;
        
        arcs.append("svg:path")
               .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
               .attr("d", arc)     //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
     .append("svg:title") //mouseover title showing the figures
       .text(function(d) { return d.data.category + ": " + formatAsPercentage(d.data.measure); });   

        d3.selectAll("g.slice").selectAll("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
       .delay(10)
       .attr("d", arcFinal )
       ;
 
   // Add a label to the larger arcs, translated to the arc centroid and rotated.
   // source: http://bl.ocks.org/1305337#index.html
   arcs.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; })
     .append("svg:text")
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arcFinal.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")"; })
       //.text(function(d) { return formatAsPercentage(d.value); })
       .text(function(d) { return d.data.category; })
       ;
    
    // Computes the label angle of an arc, converting from radians to degrees.
  function angle(d) {
      var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
      return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
  }
      
  
  // Pie chart title   
  vis.append("svg:text")
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text("Revenue Share 2012")
       .attr("class","title")
       ;      


  
 function mouseover() {
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
           //.attr("stroke","red")
           //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
           .attr("d", arcFinal3)
           ;
 }
 
 function mouseout() {
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
           //.attr("stroke","blue")
           //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
           .attr("d", arcFinal)
           ;
 }
 
 function up(d, i) {
 
    /* update bar chart when user selects piece of the pie chart */
    //updateBarChart(dataset[i].category);
    updateBarChart(d.data.category, color(i));
    updateLineChart(d.data.category, color(i));
    
 }
}

dsPieChart();

/*
############# BAR CHART ###################
-------------------------------------------
*/



var datasetBarChart = [
{ group: "All", category: "Oranges", measure: 63850.4963 }, 
{ group: "All", category: "Apples", measure: 78258.0845 }, 
{ group: "All", category: "Grapes", measure: 60610.2355 }, 
{ group: "All", category: "Figs", measure: 30493.1686 }, 
{ group: "All", category: "Mangos", measure: 56097.0151 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: "Oranges", measure: 19441.5648 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: "Apples", measure: 25922.0864 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: "Grapes", measure: 9720.7824 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: "Figs", measure: 6480.5216 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: "Mangos", measure: 19441.5648 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: "Oranges", measure: 22913.2728 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: "Apples", measure: 7637.7576 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: "Grapes", measure: 23549.7526 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: "Figs", measure: 1909.4394 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: "Mangos", measure: 7637.7576 }, 
{ group: "John", category: "Oranges", measure: 1041.5124 }, 
{ group: "John", category: "Apples", measure: 2430.1956 }, 
{ group: "John", category: "Grapes", measure: 15275.5152 }, 
{ group: "John", category: "Figs", measure: 4166.0496 }, 
{ group: "John", category: "Mangos", measure: 11803.8072 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: "Oranges", measure: 7406.3104 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: "Apples", measure: 2545.9192 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: "Grapes", measure: 1620.1304 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: "Figs", measure: 8563.5464 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: "Mangos", measure: 3008.8136 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: "Oranges", measure: 7637.7576 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: "Apples", measure: 35411.4216 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: "Grapes", measure: 8332.0992 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: "Figs", measure: 6249.0744 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: "Mangos", measure: 11803.8072 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: "Oranges", measure: 3182.399 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: "Apples", measure: 867.927 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: "Grapes", measure: 1808.18125 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: "Figs", measure: 795.59975 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: "Mangos", measure: 578.618 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: "Oranges", measure: 2227.6793 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: "Apples", measure: 3442.7771 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: "Grapes", measure: 303.77445 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: "Figs", measure: 2328.93745 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: "Mangos", measure: 1822.6467 }, 
]
;

// set initial group value
var group = "All";

function datasetBarChosen(group) {
 var ds = [];
 for (x in datasetBarChart) {
   if(datasetBarChart[x].group==group){
    ds.push(datasetBarChart[x]);
   } 
  }
 return ds;
}


function dsBarChartBasics() {

  var margin = {top: 30, right: 5, bottom: 20, left: 50},
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  colorBar = d3.scale.category20(),
  barPadding = 1
  ;
  
  return {
   margin : margin, 
   width : width, 
   height : height, 
   colorBar : colorBar, 
   barPadding : barPadding
  }   
  ;
}

function dsBarChart() {

 var firstDatasetBarChart = datasetBarChosen(group);          
 
 var basics = dsBarChartBasics();
 
 var margin = basics.margin,
  width = basics.width,
    height = basics.height,
  colorBar = basics.colorBar,
  barPadding = basics.barPadding
  ;
     
 var  xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, firstDatasetBarChart.length])
      .range([0, width])
      ;
      
 // Create linear y scale 
 // Purpose: No matter what the data is, the bar should fit into the svg area; bars should not
 // get higher than the svg height. Hence incoming data needs to be scaled to fit into the svg area.  
 var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
   // use the max funtion to derive end point of the domain (max value of the dataset)
   // do not use the min value of the dataset as min of the domain as otherwise you will not see the first bar
     .domain([0, d3.max(firstDatasetBarChart, function(d) { return d.measure; })])
     // As coordinates are always defined from the top left corner, the y position of the bar
     // is the svg height minus the data value. So you basically draw the bar starting from the top. 
     // To have the y position calculated by the range function
     .range([height, 0])
     ;
 
 //Create SVG element
 
 var svg = d3.select("#barChart")
   .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("id","barChartPlot")
      ;
 
 var plot = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      ;
             
 plot.selectAll("rect")
     .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
       return xScale(i);
   })
     .attr("width", width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding)   
   .attr("y", function(d) {
       return yScale(d.measure);
   })  
   .attr("height", function(d) {
       return height-yScale(d.measure);
   })
   .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
   ;
 
  
 // Add y labels to plot 
 
 plot.selectAll("text")
 .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
 .enter()
 .append("text")
 .text(function(d) {
   return formatAsInteger(d3.round(d.measure));
 })
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
 // Set x position to the left edge of each bar plus half the bar width
 .attr("x", function(d, i) {
   return (i * (width / firstDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
 })
 .attr("y", function(d) {
   return yScale(d.measure) + 14;
 })
 .attr("class", "yAxis")
 /* moved to CSS      
 .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
 .attr("font-size", "11px")
 .attr("fill", "white")
 */
 ;
 
 // Add x labels to chart 
 
 var xLabels = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top + height)  + ")")
      ;
 
 xLabels.selectAll("text.xAxis")
    .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.category;})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   // Set x position to the left edge of each bar plus half the bar width
         .attr("x", function(d, i) {
           return (i * (width / firstDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
         })
    .attr("y", 15)
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    //.attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif")
    ;   
  
 // Title
 
 svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", (width + margin.left + margin.right)/2)
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("class","title")    
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Overall Sales Breakdown 2012")
  ;
}

dsBarChart();

 /* ** UPDATE CHART ** */
 
/* updates bar chart on request */

function updateBarChart(group, colorChosen) {
 
  var currentDatasetBarChart = datasetBarChosen(group);
  
  var basics = dsBarChartBasics();
 
  var margin = basics.margin,
   width = basics.width,
     height = basics.height,
   colorBar = basics.colorBar,
   barPadding = basics.barPadding
   ;
  
  var  xScale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0, currentDatasetBarChart.length])
   .range([0, width])
   ;
  
   
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([0, d3.max(currentDatasetBarChart, function(d) { return d.measure; })])
       .range([height,0])
       ;
       
    var svg = d3.select("#barChart svg");
       
    var plot = d3.select("#barChartPlot")
     .datum(currentDatasetBarChart)
     ;
 
     /* Note that here we only have to select the elements - no more appending! */
    plot.selectAll("rect")
       .data(currentDatasetBarChart)
       .transition()
   .duration(750)
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
       return xScale(i);
   })
     .attr("width", width / currentDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding)   
   .attr("y", function(d) {
       return yScale(d.measure);
   })  
   .attr("height", function(d) {
       return height-yScale(d.measure);
   })
   .attr("fill", colorChosen)
   ;
  
  plot.selectAll("text.yAxis") // target the text element(s) which has a yAxis class defined
   .data(currentDatasetBarChart)
   .transition()
   .duration(750)
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("x", function(d, i) {
       return (i * (width / currentDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / currentDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
     })
     .attr("y", function(d) {
       return yScale(d.measure) + 14;
     })
     .text(function(d) {
    return formatAsInteger(d3.round(d.measure));
     })
     .attr("class", "yAxis")      
  ;
  

  svg.selectAll("text.title") // target the text element(s) which has a title class defined
   .attr("x", (width + margin.left + margin.right)/2)
   .attr("y", 15)
   .attr("class","title")    
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text(group + "'s Sales Breakdown 2012")
  ;
}


/*
############# LINE CHART ##################
-------------------------------------------
*/

var datasetLineChart = [
{ group: "All", category: 2008, measure: 289309 }, 
{ group: "All", category: 2009, measure: 234998 }, 
{ group: "All", category: 2010, measure: 310900 }, 
{ group: "All", category: 2011, measure: 223900 }, 
{ group: "All", category: 2012, measure: 234500 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: 2008, measure: 81006.52 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: 2009, measure: 70499.4 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: 2010, measure: 96379 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: 2011, measure: 64931 }, 
{ group: "Sam", category: 2012, measure: 70350 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: 2008, measure: 63647.98 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: 2009, measure: 61099.48 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: 2010, measure: 87052 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: 2011, measure: 58214 }, 
{ group: "Peter", category: 2012, measure: 58625 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: 2008, measure: 23144.72 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: 2009, measure: 14099.88 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: 2010, measure: 15545 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: 2011, measure: 11195 }, 
{ group: "Rick", category: 2012, measure: 11725 }, 
{ group: "John", category: 2008, measure: 34717.08 }, 
{ group: "John", category: 2009, measure: 30549.74 }, 
{ group: "John", category: 2010, measure: 34199 }, 
{ group: "John", category: 2011, measure: 33585 }, 
{ group: "John", category: 2012, measure: 35175 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: 2008, measure: 69434.16 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: 2009, measure: 46999.6 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: 2010, measure: 62180 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: 2011, measure: 40302 }, 
{ group: "Lenny", category: 2012, measure: 42210 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: 2008, measure: 7232.725 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: 2009, measure: 4699.96 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: 2010, measure: 6218 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: 2011, measure: 8956 }, 
{ group: "Paul", category: 2012, measure: 9380 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: 2008, measure: 10125.815 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: 2009, measure: 7049.94 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: 2010, measure: 9327 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: 2011, measure: 6717 }, 
{ group: "Steve", category: 2012, measure: 7035 }
]
;

// set initial category value
var group = "All";

function datasetLineChartChosen(group) {
 var ds = [];
 for (x in datasetLineChart) {
   if(datasetLineChart[x].group==group){
    ds.push(datasetLineChart[x]);
   } 
  }
 return ds;
}

function dsLineChartBasics() {

 var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 0, left: 50},
     width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
     height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom
     ;
  
  return {
   margin : margin, 
   width : width, 
   height : height
  }   
  ;
}


function dsLineChart() {

 var firstDatasetLineChart = datasetLineChartChosen(group);    
 
 var basics = dsLineChartBasics();
 
 var margin = basics.margin,
  width = basics.width,
    height = basics.height
  ;

 var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, firstDatasetLineChart.length-1])
     .range([0, width])
     ;

 var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, d3.max(firstDatasetLineChart, function(d) { return d.measure; })])
     .range([height, 0])
     ;
 
 var line = d3.svg.line()
     //.x(function(d) { return xScale(d.category); })
     .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); })
     .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.measure); })
     ;
 
 var svg = d3.select("#lineChart").append("svg")
     .datum(firstDatasetLineChart)
     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     // create group and move it so that margins are respected (space for axis and title)
     
 var plot = svg
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
     .attr("id", "lineChartPlot")
     ;

  /* descriptive titles as part of plot -- start */
 var dsLength=firstDatasetLineChart.length;

 plot.append("text")
  .text(firstDatasetLineChart[dsLength-1].measure)
  .attr("id","lineChartTitle2")
  .attr("x",width/2)
  .attr("y",height/2) 
  ;
 /* descriptive titles -- end */
     
 plot.append("path")
     .attr("class", "line")
     .attr("d", line) 
     // add color
  .attr("stroke", "lightgrey")
     ;
   
 plot.selectAll(".dot")
     .data(firstDatasetLineChart)
     .enter().append("circle")
     .attr("class", "dot")
     //.attr("stroke", function (d) { return d.measure==datasetMeasureMin ? "red" : (d.measure==datasetMeasureMax ? "green" : "steelblue") } )
     .attr("fill", function (d) { return d.measure==d3.min(firstDatasetLineChart, function(d) { return d.measure; }) ? "red" : (d.measure==d3.max(firstDatasetLineChart, function(d) { return d.measure; }) ? "green" : "white") } )
     //.attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return d.measure==datasetMeasureMin || d.measure==datasetMeasureMax ? "3px" : "1.5px"} )
     .attr("cx", line.x())
     .attr("cy", line.y())
     .attr("r", 3.5)
     .attr("stroke", "lightgrey")
     .append("title")
     .text(function(d) { return d.category + ": " + formatAsInteger(d.measure); })
     ;

 svg.append("text")
  .text("Performance 2012")
  .attr("id","lineChartTitle1") 
  .attr("x",margin.left + ((width + margin.right)/2))
  .attr("y", 10)
  ;

}

dsLineChart();


 /* ** UPDATE CHART ** */
 
/* updates bar chart on request */
function updateLineChart(group, colorChosen) {

 var currentDatasetLineChart = datasetLineChartChosen(group);   

 var basics = dsLineChartBasics();
 
 var margin = basics.margin,
  width = basics.width,
    height = basics.height
  ;

 var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, currentDatasetLineChart.length-1])
     .range([0, width])
     ;

 var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, d3.max(currentDatasetLineChart, function(d) { return d.measure; })])
     .range([height, 0])
     ;
 
 var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.measure); })
    ;

   var plot = d3.select("#lineChartPlot")
    .datum(currentDatasetLineChart)
    ;
    
 /* descriptive titles as part of plot -- start */
 var dsLength=currentDatasetLineChart.length;
 
 plot.select("text")
  .text(currentDatasetLineChart[dsLength-1].measure)
  ;
 /* descriptive titles -- end */
    
 plot
 .select("path")
  .transition()
  .duration(750)       
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line) 
    // add color
  .attr("stroke", colorChosen)
    ;
    
 var path = plot
  .selectAll(".dot")
    .data(currentDatasetLineChart)
    .transition()
  .duration(750)
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("fill", function (d) { return d.measure==d3.min(currentDatasetLineChart, function(d) { return d.measure; }) ? "red" : (d.measure==d3.max(currentDatasetLineChart, function(d) { return d.measure; }) ? "green" : "white") } )
    .attr("cx", line.x())
    .attr("cy", line.y())
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    // add color
  .attr("stroke", colorChosen)
    ;
    
    path
    .selectAll("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.category + ": " + formatAsInteger(d.measure); })  
    ;  

}
```

```css
#pieChart {    
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:10px;
 width:400px;
 height: 400px; 
}



#lineChart {    
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:410px;
 height: 150px;
}

#barChart {
 position:absolute;
 top:160px;
 left:410px;
 height: 250px;
}

.slice {
   font-size: 12pt;
   font-family: Verdana;
   fill: white; //svg specific - instead of color
   font-weight: bold; 
    } 

/*for line chart*/
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges; //The shape-rendering property is an SVG attribute, used here to make sure our axis and its tick mark lines are pixel-perfect. 
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  /*stroke: steelblue;*/
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.dot {
  /*fill: white;*/
  /*stroke: steelblue;*/
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
    

.axis text {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.title {
  font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 15px; 
  
}

.xAxis {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    fill: black;
}  

.yAxis {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    fill: white;
}

  
table {
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border: 0px; 
 font-family: Verdana; 
 color: #5C5558;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: right;   
}

td {
 padding-left: 10px;  
}

#lineChartTitle1 {
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size  : 14px;
 fill       : lightgrey;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-anchor: middle;
}

#lineChartTitle2 {
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size  : 72px;
 fill       : grey;
 text-anchor: middle;
 font-weight: bold;
 /*font-style: italic;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="pieChart"></div>
<div id="barChart"></div>  
<div id="lineChart"></div>
```

Comment: This seems the way to go. I'm using AngularJS + D3. Is it an obstacle for what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be. As a matter of fact you might even have an easier time  updating/filtering the information since it's all "connected" already :).

Comment: Yeah, I'm using directives for each graph, and the information binding is much easier, since each graph knows exactly what to observe.

Comment: Feel free to mark as answer if this is what you needed :)